# Has the 5-minute grace period been removed?

Tags: support

I just gave an answer and [edited it](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/posts/20979/revisions) shortly thereafter. As you can see from the timestamps in the link, the two actions have been performed about 2 minutes and a half apart.

So this prompts my question: has the 5-minutes grace period been modified? I remember that during this period any edit would not be recorded by the system and simply shown as 1 single action.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [this MSE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/255845/wheres-my-5-minute-grace-period-gone) the 5 minute grace period has not gone anywhere, but there is more than just the 5 minute timer that determines if an edit is rolled into the previous revision or a new one created.

According to t[his answer from Shog9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/251876/265657):

> Edits will be rolled into the previous revision if the previous revision was created by the same author and none of the following conditions are present:
>
> - The previous revision was created 5 minutes or more in the past
> - A comment has been added to the post since the previous revision by anyone other than the editor.
> - An answer has been added to the post since the previous revision
> - The previous revision was a rollback
> - The new revision is a rollback

This behavior was implemented in March 2015.

Comment: ah, I was not aware of those conditions, thanks!